# Pannier rear rack with no eyelets

Tags: rack, panniers

I have a rear bike rack similar to this [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EZZBH0S), but I have no top or bottom eyelets on my Lemond bike. I want to attach it with p-clamps for a 3 day tour. How much weight can p-clamps hold? Do you have any recommendations on which specific p-clamps to get?

Comment: If you buy good quality clamps they should be able to handle whatever weight you throw at them.  But you should go a little easy since the mounting will not be as stiff as with eyelets and so the rack will bound around a bit more.  Another option is adapters that fit around the axle and are secured with the axle nut or QR.

Comment: Is there any weight limit (other than the rack limit) for the adapter that goes on the rear QR? Also, would that work for my rack which only has one hole on each side at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the upper mounts, there are brackets that clamp on the seat stay or the seat post and provide the regular braze-ons.

I'm betting the p-clamps will hold more weight than the rack will, however try it well before your tour.

Comment: I was going to use P-clamps for a commuter bike, but the clamps I bought where too big for the bike and a new bike negated the reason I bought them.  I'll let somebody else come up with a better answer for the lower.